# Properties: Get Accessor vs Expression-Bodied Member

Tags: c#, properties

These seem to be practically equivalent:

```cs
bool PropertyAsExpressionBody => true;
bool PropertyAsGetAccessor {
    get {
        return true; // or just { get => true; }
    }
}
```

Is there any functional difference between declaring a `get` accessor (assuming you don't want/need a setter) and an expression-bodied property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same pict.. thing.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties):

> Starting with C# 6, read-only properties can implement the get
> accessor as an expression-bodied member. In this case, neither the get
> accessor keyword nor the return keyword is used.

and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties):

> Starting with C# 7.0, you can use expression body definitions to
> implement property get and set accessors.